# microsoft visual studio is unable to load this document. Unable to create the type with the name OLEDB

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have insatalled VS 2022 and when I try open a SSIS package I got the following error:

microsoft visual studio is unable to load this document. Unable to create the type with the name OLEDB

I do not know waht I should to do in order to solve this.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you installed SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) and if you do, try reinstalling SSDT for Visual Studio. Sometimes, a corrupted installation can cause issues with SSIS package loading

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). If it doesn't work, lower your version further. Finally, reinstalling SSIS components. I hope this helps.